# Subsetting a list, then using table() on each sublist

Tags: r

I have a list of 1200 species with attributes, stored as a vector:

```
x <- list(Species1=c("A", "B", "C"), Species2=c("A","C","D"), Species3=c("B", "C","E"))
```

The vectors vary in length. For each Species in `x`, i have taxonomic information:

```
tax <- data.frame(Species=c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3"), Taxa=c("Apes", "Birds", "Apes"))
```

I want to

```
table(unlist(x))
```

but after subsetting `x` with `tax$Taxa`

Desired Output

[image: Apes]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `stack` the named `list` into a two column 'data.frame' `merge` with the 'tax' dataset and get the `table` of subset of columns

```
table(merge(stack(x), tax, by.x = "ind", by.y = "Species")[3:2])
#     values
#Taxa    A B C D E
#  Apes  1 2 2 0 1
#  Birds 1 0 1 1 0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidvyerse)
set_names(x, tax$Taxa[match(names(x), tax$Species)]) %>%
   enframe %>% 
   unnest %>% 
   count(name, value) %>% 
   spread(value, n, fill = 0)
```

Comment: thanks, saved a lot of time. base r solution worked for me like this: table(merge(stack(x), tax, by.x="ind", by.y="Species")[,3:2]) (a "," seems to be missing).

Comment: @nouse  Glad to know that it is working.  Sorrry, I tried on a fresh session and it is still working for me (without any change in `,`

Comment: @nouse Okay, got it.  Your original dataset might be `matrix` instead of `data.frame`